Escaped dotes in a key of yaml saucelabs config file
I need to specify custom testOption in YAML file which is used to run the tests on SauceLabs:
this is the test option:
androidx.benchmark.suppressErrors: DEBUGGABLE

it's the argument which google recommends: link
But I am getting an error:
"Map key androidx.benchmark.suppressErrors contains dots but no replacement was configured!"
I was trying to use different ways of escaping those dotes in config file, like: "/", "", "''", but nothing worked for me
What will be the proper way to escape dotes in a key of YAML file?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
